# Passing class instance and method as argument to another function in C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I have two classes. One class has a method that takes a function as a parameter and that passed function is expected to have a string as an argument. For example:

```
class Dog{
public:
    void doDogThings(std::function <void(std::string)> theFunction);

}

class Cat{
public:
    void doCatThings(std::string stringInput);
}
```

And here they are in action

```
int main(){
   Cat aCat;
   Dog aDog;
   std::string theString = "Oh jeez";
   aDog.doDogThings(<< insert cat's method and argument here >>);
   .....
```

This is the part that is fouling me up here; I know I should use

```
bind(&Cat::doCatThings, ref(aCat) ....?.....);
```

But I am stuck on how to pass the argument for the Cat method as a parameter to this function pointer. 
Any help would be greatly be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The correct `bind` syntax would be:

```
aDog.doDogThings(std::bind(
    &Cat::doCatThings, std::ref(aCat), std::placeholders::_1));
```

The "placeholder" `_1` means "the first argument to the resulting functor will get used here to pass to the bound callable".

But I really don't recommend using `std::bind` in almost any circumstance.  It has some annoying gotchas, is often tricky to get correct, tricky to read again after you've written a use of it, and results in the most terrible compiler errors any time you get something slightly wrong.  Lambdas can do anything `std::bind` can do and quite a bit more, without most of those problems.

So instead, I'd suggest:

```
aDog.doDogThings(
    [&aCat](std::string stringInput)
    { aCat.doCatThings(std::move(stringInput)); }
);
```

Comment: So background motivation. I have a couple class managers and I am attempting to limit the amount of the coupling between the classes.I have a client manager that is responsible for managing incoming and outgoing messages and a window manager that displays stuff on screen using ncurses. Shared between the two class managers is a ringbuffer that is used to store ingoing and outgoing messages so that they can be displayed in a window. The window needs to be updated if a) a message is received b) a message is sent.

Comment: The goal as to minimize the amount of coupling between the two classes by passing class instances and a corresponding method to trigger updates. When I attempt to adapt your solution it throws an error message. I get the following
Parameter type mismatch: Class '__bind<void (ClientManager::*)(string), reference_wrapper<ClientManager>, const placeholders::_1ph<1> &>' is not compatible with class "function<void(string)>'
I don't really know if am passing and using the methods correctly at this point because I have never done this kind of thing before.

Comment: Not sure what that could mean. Does the little program at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00c817795b7ba652 compile on your system?  If you can come up with the shortest possible program that gives you the same error message, that could make a good separate question here.

Comment: I got it to work. It was wanting some kind of import and once I did that when I adapted your example it worked exactly as intended.